# Refresh RecyclerView When Delete Items

Tags: android

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final BookViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        holder.iBookName.setText(uploadCurrent.getBookName());
        holder.iBookAuthor.setText(uploadCurrent.getBookAuthor());
        holder.iBookPublisher.setText(uploadCurrent.getBookPublisher());
        /*holder.iBookDesc.setText(uploadCurrent.getBookDesc());*/
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getBookImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.blank)
                .fit()
                .into(holder.iBookImage);
        holder.iBookMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, holder.iBookMenu);
                popup.inflate(R.menu.cardview_menu);
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.add_my_list:
                                break;
                            case R.id.delete_my_list:
                                deleteBook(mUploads.get(position).getBookId());
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void deleteBook(String id) {
        DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books").child(id);
        dR.removeValue();
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Book deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }
}
```

I created a book app. I designed cardview in popup menu and you can delete item. I can delete item but it still looks. My problem is recyclerview doesn't refresh when delete items. Can you help me? I tried a lot of method in here, but i can't resolve my problem.

Comment: there are many methods in RecyclerView.Adapter. You can use notifyItemDeleted

Comment: please chose a best answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must be after delete item refresh adapter

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final BookViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        holder.iBookName.setText(uploadCurrent.getBookName());
        holder.iBookAuthor.setText(uploadCurrent.getBookAuthor());
        holder.iBookPublisher.setText(uploadCurrent.getBookPublisher());
        /*holder.iBookDesc.setText(uploadCurrent.getBookDesc());*/
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getBookImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.blank)
                .fit()
                .into(holder.iBookImage);
        holder.iBookMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, holder.iBookMenu);
                popup.inflate(R.menu.cardview_menu);
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.add_my_list:
                                break;
                            case R.id.delete_my_list:
                                deleteBook(mUploads.get(position).getBookId(),position);
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
            }
        });
    }

private void deleteBook(String id,int position) {
        DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books").child(id);
        dR.removeValue();
        // position of item delete in your adapter model
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Book deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: `notifyItemRemoved(position);` is required int , but mine is String `private void deleteBook(String id)` how can resolve this

Comment: change this line also  -
  deleteBook(mUploads.get(position).getBookId(),position);

Comment: Its refreshed but added new one. Does not appear in the database

Comment: @Mustafa Kemal Öz 

you sure this code is remove item of db? 

 DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books").child(id);
        dR.removeValue();

Comment: @Mustafa Kemal Öz
so good ! you can chose my answer is the best answer ( chose tick on the left )

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
notifyDataSetChanged() 
}
```

in item remove method.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of frustration with your same issue, I modified my `RecyclerViewAdapter` to use a `ListAdapter`.

Here is how my `RecyclerViewAdapter` looks like:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends ListAdapter<YourObjectType, RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ...

    public RecyclerViewAdapter() {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
        ...
    }

    public static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<YourObjectType> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<YourObjectType>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull YourObjectType oldItem, @NonNull YourObjectType newItem) {
            return oldItem.compareTo(newItem)==0; //I added a compareTo method to myObjectClass so that I can compare them.
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull YourObjectType oldItem, @NonNull YourObjectType newItem) {
            return oldItem.compareTo(newItem)==0; //I added a compareTo method to myObjectClass so that I can compare them.
        }
    };

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ...
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ...
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your activity you can initialize your `RecyclerView` by doing this:

```
private void initRecyclerView(){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.invalidate();
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

And call `adapter.submitList(yourList);` any time the list updates.

In my case I call `submitList` in my `OnDataChange` callback.

I followed [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPPMygGxiEo&t=596s) to achieve this.